# db2_fetch_assoc() not returning the next row even when one exists

Tags: php, db2

db2_fetch_assoc() isn't finding the next row when called from certain places - even though there are more rows in the recordset.

goQueryDB2() connects to the database and runs a query.  It is able to return the first row in the recordset using db2_fetch_assoc() and the second row in the recordset by calling the outside function getNextRowDB2() (which does the same thing).

The recordset resource is returned from that function ($result).  However when getNextRowDB2() is then called again with $result supplied as a parameter, the third row in the recordset is NOT returned - in fact it can't find anything and throws a warning (Warning: db2_fetch_assoc() [function.db2-fetch-assoc]: Fetch Failure).

You can see from the output of "No results found in Resource id #12" the name of the resource has been effectively passed to the getNextRowDB2() function - but for some reason it no longer find any rows in that recordset.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?  Or even confirm if you agree this code looks ok?

Is there something that makes the DB2 recordset resource inaccessible outside the function in which it was called?

**This worked ok in MySQL (I have to convert to DB2).**

So this code:

```
function goQueryDB2($sql)
{
  if($con = db2_connect("MASTER", "USER", "PASSWORD"))
  {
    echo "<li>Connected to master database</li>";   
  }

  if($result = db2_exec($con, $sql))
  {
    echo "<li>SQL Query ran successfully</li>"; 
  }

  //Just proving some data can be returned as this point
  $row = db2_fetch_assoc($result);

  if(sizeof($row) > 0)
  {
    echo "<li>db2_fetch_assoc returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: " . $result . ") that has " . sizeof($row) . " fields</li>"; 
  }

  //Just proving some data can be returned as this point
  $row = getNextRowDB2($result);
  if(sizeof($row) > 0)
  {
    echo "<li>getNextRow() returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: " . $result . ") the has " . sizeof($row) . " fields</li>"; 
  }

  return $result;
}

function getNextRowDB2($result)
{
    if($row = db2_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        return $row;    
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<li>No results found in " . $result . "</li>";    
    }
}

echo "<h2>goQueryDB2()</h2>";
$result = goQueryDB2("SELECT * FROM users");

echo "<h2>getNextRowDB2()</h2>";
$row = getNextRowDB2($result);
```

Produces this output:

```
goQueryDB2()
Connected to master database
SQL Query ran successfully
db2_fetch_assoc returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: Resource id #12) that has 25 fields
getNextRow() returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: Resource id #12) the has 25 fields
getNextRowDB2()

Warning: db2_fetch_assoc() [function.db2-fetch-assoc]: Fetch Failure in /home/portal/includes/functionsSecurity.php on line 262
No results found in Resource id #12
```

Comment: How do you know there's another row available? You haven't called `db2_num_rows($result)` anywhere I see...

Comment: That's a fair comment based on what I posted, but I have confirmed there around 2,500 rows by querying directly through CLI.  Also if I repeat this code within the main function "  $row = getNextRowDB2($result);
  if(sizeof($row) > 0)
  {
    echo "<li>getNextRow() returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: " . $result . ") the has " . sizeof($row) . " fields</li>"; 
  }" It continues to show the third, fourth record...etc

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by using a persistent connection:

```
$con = db2_pconnect("MASTER", "USER", "PASSWORD")
```

I assume that even though the name of the resource ("Resource id #12") is passed back from the function, the DB2 connection and all returned resources stop existing at the end of the function in which they were called - unless a persistent connection is used.

This is unique to DB2 as I found persistent connections weren't necessary to achieve this in MySQL.